# When trying to run a simple ant script from gradle, I am getting "srcdir does not exist"

Tags: java, ant, gradle, build

I am trying to run a simple bare minimum ant script from gradle. 
My build.gradle only has the ant import statement

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

I have my ant build.xml as below. Note that this works fine when I use ant compile.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="SampleProject" default="antCompile" basedir="SampleProject">
<target name="antCompile">     
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" /> 
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" /> 
</target> 
<target name="compress" depends="antCompile"> 
    <mkdir dir="build/jar" /> 
    <jar destfile="build/jar/SampleProject.jar" basedir="build/classes" /> 
</target>
</project>
```

Butwhen I try to run the antCompile target using the following in command prompt.

```
gradle antCompile
```

I get the "srcdir doesnot exist" exception.

However if I modify the build.xml to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="SampleProject" default="antCompile" basedir=".">

    <target name="antCompile">     
        <mkdir dir="SampleProject/build/classes" /> 
        <javac includeAntRuntime="false" srcdir="SampleProject/src" destdir="SampleProject/build/classes" /> 
    </target> 

    <target name="compress" depends="antCompile"> 
        <mkdir dir="SampleProject/build/jar" /> 
        <jar destfile="SampleProject/build/jar/SampleProject.jar" basedir="SampleProject/build/classes" /> 
    </target>

</project>
```

I am able to run the script successfully from gradle. 
Note that in both cases compiling using the ant tool works.

I am not able to identify why my first approach doesn't work when running through gradle. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a limitation of `org/gradle/api/internal/project/DefaultAntBuilder.java`
in gradle-core-xx.jar

```
  public void importBuild(Object antBuildFile, Transformer<? extends String, ? super String> taskNamer) {
    File file = this.gradleProject.file(antBuildFile);
    File baseDir = file.getParentFile();

    Set existingAntTargets = new HashSet(getAntProject().getTargets().keySet());
    File oldBaseDir = getAntProject().getBaseDir();
    getAntProject().setBaseDir(baseDir);
```

means the basedir is set to directory containing the antscript not to the value of
 basedir attribute of imported ant file.
-- EDIT --
Found an [open issue on gradle.org](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2039)

Comment: Thank you pointing it out and also for the link to the open issue :)

Comment: And also any thoughts on the best possible work-around? My initial reaction would be not to force a change on my ant file. Thanks!

Comment: @Harypain The open issue contains two possible workarounds, did you try them ?

Comment: Yes I did try them. 
First workaround was to create a second ant file. 
Second was to set the baseDir on the created AntTarget gradle tasks. 
The first one looks 'bad' so I am sticking to the second one. Just wanted to know if there were any one better.

Comment: @Harypain Best would be to move your ant scripts to gradle. If that is no option i would stick with the second option - setting the basedir.